# DOTween tween a float/int

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using DOTween library in my Unity project (http://dotween.demigiant.com/documentation.php).
I am trying to tween an int or a float but I am not getting around anywhere in documentation how one can tween a value.

```
public int valInt = 5;
public float valFloat = 5.2f;

public void Start(){
  valFloat.DOFloat(2.3f, 10.0f); //Does not work
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DOTween.To()`;

```
float valFloat = 0f;
DOTween.To(() => valFloat, x => valFloat = x, 0f, 1f);
```